# Drawing in nonclient area

Tags: c#, uwp

I am playing with uwp, writing an app designed to run on a windows desktop machine.
I want to draw a full screen colored border that overlays everything you see. 
I added an image below to show the desired effect, the green border is what I want to draw. This border should not receive any input whatsoever, a purely visual effect.

In wpf I would have used an invisible fullscreen window and draw on that.
But in uwp this is not possible afaik.

How would one approach such a problem, is there a way to draw directly on the screen, what areas should I look at?

I am a beginning developer so if you see the need please don't skip over very basic ideas here, assuming I know little.

Thank you for your time!

[image].

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would guess that UWP applications are not allowed to do this. Why are you creating a UWP app instead of a desktop app?

Comment: Mainly to learn the 'new' way that Microsoft want everybody to work. Though the more I dive into UWP the more boxed in I feel atm.

Comment: Well, the new way they want everyone to work does not involve drawing directly on the desktop. :-) It's not just the latest design fad, it's an entirely different conceptual model. Or, to put it the way Tim Sweeney did, ["Universal Windows Platform can, should, must, and will die"](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/mar/04/microsoft-monopolise-pc-games-development-epic-games-gears-of-war).

Comment: It appears so yes, I feel like UWP is telling me what kind of clothing to wear and when to do so if I want to party with it.  Ok I think I know enough for now, tnx :)

Comment: This is completely off-topic, but why do you feel *"boxed-in"* when targeting the UWP? This is not like .NET; you can directly call a huge subset of the Windows API. It's native, too, so you don't have .NET's poor startup performance either, or the pitfalls of non-deterministic garbage collection. @CodyGray: I don't really follow Sweeney's reasoning, and the quote you replayed has a big *"if"* in front of it. I don't see how UWP is a lock-down, with side-loading being supported through PowerShell scripts that ship with the OS. Smells a bit like FUD, really.

Comment: @CodyGray: I really tried, but cannot see what Tim Sweeney is going on about. Why even target UWP as a game developer? Why not keep using the Windows API? It's not going away any time soon. And why not mention, that Epic Games does support and sell games on iOS, for years? The most complete lock-in there is, and yet, Epic Games somehow managed to survive... Had it been impossible for him to put things into perspective? Anyway, as I said, I have not the slightest idea what point Sweeney was trying to make.

Comment: @IInspectable Indeed, it was a bit of a joke. Although I thought the Sweeney article was interesting to read, I really don't have enough insight on UWP at this point to make a judgment call. I am unwilling to update to Windows 10 as my primary operating system, so I'm not doing any development of UWP apps yet. From what I've read about it, though, there is definitely some boxing in with UWP that I don't like. It is an improvement over .NET in a technical sense, because it's all native code, but the marketing from Microsoft seems in many ways worse than Sweeney's brand of FUD.

Comment: @CodyGray: UWP is a unified platform, implemented using the Windows Runtime. WinRT is a COM library that wraps the Windows API. You can still directly call into the majority of [Win32 and COM APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt592904.aspx), with almost complete CRT support (see [CRT functions not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj606124.aspx)); support for the C++ Standard Library is even more complete. As regurgitated in comments (albeit wrong): There are no UWP-only features. Any desktop app can instantiate any UWP type. No restrictions.

Comment: @CodyGray: I don't understand what Sweeney is trying to get at. There is **zero** requirement to target the UWP for games (but if you want to port some code over, it's almost trivially easy). If you want access to UWP types, your desktop application can instantiate them. If you want your own market, Microsoft allows for that as well. It's almost like Sweeney has forgotten how to analyze a problem, and find solutions. Or simply isn't very good at writing articles.